# Public Calendar Events doesn't show up as Open Activities against related record

Tags: tasks, event, activities, calendar

We have a public calendar event with WhoId as Contact and WhatId as Custom Object.But it doesn't seems to be linked to Contact or Custom Object via  Open Activities.Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can my Public Calendar events show up on the Open Activity related list?

**[From Salesforce Knowledge Article Number: 000181946](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181946)**

Description
Some customers would like for their Tasks/Events in their Public Calendar to be linked to a specific record.  Also for those Tasks/Events to show up in the Open Activity related list on the record detail page.

Resolution
At this time, Public Calendar events do not show up at the record level in the Open Activity related list

Workaround:
Customers should use the Calendar on their home page to enter events they want to show up on the record level.

Suggestion:
Customers requesting this functionality can also be directed to vote for an existing Idea on the Ideas Exchange.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpN0AAK

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a custom VF Page for this functionality. You just need to query `Event` records whose `WhatId` corresponds to your object. The basic gist:

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c" extension="MyObjectEventsExtension">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!events}" var="event">
        <apex:repeat value="{!fields} var="field">
            <apex:column value="{!event[field]}" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class MyObjectEventsExtension
{
    final Id recordId;

    public MyObjectEventsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.recordId = controller.getId();
    }

    // define from field set if you want it to be configurable
    public List<String> fields { get; private set; }
    public List<MyObject__c> records
    {
        get
        {
            if (records == null)
            {
                records = [SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE WhatId = :recordId];
                // need string query to merge in display fields if you go dynamic route
            }
            return records;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```